# On continuous seminorms on Fréchet-Stein algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a discretely valued complete non-archimedean field and $U$ be a left Fréchet-Stein algebra as defined in [Algebras of p-adic distributions and admissible representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206056), with a Fréchet-Stein presentation $U=\varprojlim U_{n}$.

In particular, each of the $U_{n}$ is a noetherian Banach $K$-algebra, and the transition maps $U_{n+1}\rightarrow U_{n}$ are continuous, have dense image, and turn $U_{n}$ into a right $U_{n+1}$-module. The algebra $U$ is a Fréchet algebra with respect to the inverse limit topology.
Consider the set $\mathcal{Q}_{U}$, of continuous seminorms $q$ on $U$, such that the completion with respect to this seminorm, is left noetherian. Denote by $q_{n}$ the seminorms on $U$ such that their correspondent completion is $U_{n}$. We can endow $\mathcal{Q}_{U}$ with a partial order given by $q\leq q'$ if $q(x)\leq q'(x)$ for every $x\in U$. In section 7.2 in [D-modules on rigid analytic spaces I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02215), it is stated that the $q_{n}$ form a cofinal family in $\mathcal{Q}_{U}$, that is, for every continuous seminorm $q$, there is a natural $n$ such that $q\leq q_{n}$. I  would like to see an explanaition of this fact. In particular, I fail to understand how the left-noetherianness condition affects the behaviour of the seminorm.